# I would like to copy a file to a new directory and then rename it using the datetime :: Python

Tags: python, datetime, rename

So my title says it, but looking around for help on the move and then renaming it with the datetime hasn't proven as simple as I had hoped. Here is the code so far:

```
import os
import shutil
import time
timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")

srcfile = '/Users/foo/bar/log.html'
dstroot = '/Users/foo/bar/newlogs/'


assert not os.path.isabs(log.html)
dstdir =  os.path.join(dstroot, os.path.dirname(log.html))
shutil.copy(log.html, dstdir)

os.rename ('log.html', timestr.'lognew.html')
```

Comment: John got the answer right, but - One note on atomic file operations: Make sure to copy it to a tmpfile name into the directory, _then_ rename it.. That way you're guaranteed never to have a zero byte file accidentally)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the instances of `log.html` need to be quoted.

```
assert not os.path.isabs('log.html')
dstdir =  os.path.join(dstroot, os.path.dirname('log.html'))
shutil.copy('log.html', dstdir)
```

(Or maybe you meant to use the `srcfile` variable in those spots?)

To concatenate strings use `+`:

```
timestr + 'lognew.html'
```